# How to give preference to the user snippet over snippet of extension in vs code?

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Hey guys i created my own printf code snippet in c.json file

```
"printf": {
    "prefix": "printf",
    "body": [
      "printf(\"$1\"$2);",
      "$3"
    ],
    "description": "Printf statement"
  }
```

But in the main window when i type printf, the printf code snippet of c/c++ extension comes first in suggestion later comes mine.
Is there any way that i can give my user code snippet more preference than the extension's snippet?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of that extension's `printf` snippet altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings, you could play around with

> Editor: Snippet Suggestions
> Controls whether snippets are shown with
> other suggestions and how they are sorted.

Or you could set your prefix to 'aprintf' or 'myprintf'.